# Best way to re-create a dynamic table in css

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-tables

Curious to see what method other people are using to re-create fluid tables in CSS.

Back in table days, if there wasn't a width set the table would just auto-adjust to make the columns fit.

Let's say: We have a 2column "table" display a product. Image on the left, Name/Description on the right.

Let's also say: Image width is unknown.

Typically in this situation, what I do is float the image left and hide the overflow on the content to the right. If we have rows of data though, this simply will not work as everything will have different margins.

Yes, We could just say: Images will not be bigger then x so let's float the image left and set a left margin on the right side content. - or even float the content on the right to the right.

Doing this really isn't a problem, however I am just curious as if there was a way to make it all fluid... Some of these sites I'm working on have enormous stylesheets and I'm trying to keep the styles to a minimum.

Our designer likes to use this image to the left, content to the right - or even reversed... image to the right content to the left A LOT, but it seems as the margins are always different per situation. I really want to make this a re-usable class.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/simoncereska/dGnzJ/   Take a look at this. If you add class .p-r to .img you'll get another view. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: hrm- I don't think so. Unless I'm misunderstanding you... Basically if you were to add another row below that - same text but with a 100x100 image the text on both rows should line up

Comment: oh, I misunderstood you. Will think about that today